# Is there some way to include a comment function in standalone quarto html file?

Tags: quarto

Q in title.

I use Quarto to html to write short reports and I want readers to be able to leave comments (and save them). The file must be inside a dropbox folder, if that matters. I prefer to use html over pdf in this case because I need it to be interactive.